# Why do we need to specify security_groups while creating EKS cluster by Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-eks

I am trying to create an EKS cluster by Ansible using `community.aws.eks_cluster` module with following playbook snippet,

```
- name: Create EKS cluster
  community.aws.eks_cluster:
    name: "{{ eks_cluster.name }}"
    state: present
    version: "{{ eks_cluster.version }}"
    role_arn: "{{ eks_role_created.iam_role.arn }}"
    subnets:
      - "{{ subnet1_id }}"
      - "{{ subnet2_id }}"
    wait: true
  register: eks_creation_result
```

When I try to execute it, I got the following error message,

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "state is present but all of the following are missing: security_groups"}
```

In my perspective, the security groups specified here is for cluster level instead of node group level. Correct me if it's wrong.

Then, I check the official document of Ansible from [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/eks_cluster_module.html#ansible-collections-community-aws-eks-cluster-module), they didn't mention the usage of this field and state it is mandatory.

Moreover, I check the official document of AWS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/sec-group-reqs.html) about the security groups of EKS cluster. They mentioned,

```
When you create a cluster, Amazon EKS creates a security group named...
```

I was expecting when we create a EKS cluster, it will automatically create a security group to control the cluster level inbound and outbound rules.

So, is the error from Ansible means I need to create a security group in advance, or I have misunderstood the error?

If Ansible ask me to create a security group in advance, is it a misbehave as AWS should create a security group automatically during EKS cluster creation?

Updates:

I tried to create a security group in advance and put its ID in the `security_groups` field. Then create an EKS cluster. The result shows that AWS still helps to create a new security group like the docs I shared above.

I saw the security group I created becomes one of the Additional security groups of my new EKS cluster. So why Additional security groups is mandatory on Ansible perspective?

Update 2:
Using latest community.aws.eks_cluster module and got the same error.

Comment: You use the old `community.awx.aws_eks_cluster` name which redirects to current `community.aws.eks_cluster`, so make sure you're up-to-date and using the latest ansible and `community.aws` collection versions. Dev pace is fast in ansible and this might have already been addressed. I this is still an issue on the latest stack and you believe it's a bug, the best place to file and discuss it is probably [the collection issues on github](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.aws/issues). See https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.aws/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: @Zeitounator I have tried to use the community.aws.eks_cluster module. Before I report it as a bug, I wanna make sure I didn't make any silly mistake or misuse of the module.